# Does Documentation deprecate canonical dupe target lists?

Tags: discussion, documentation, canonical

There are various old "What does this symbol mean" lists of community wiki canonical dupe targets which seem to have a great acceptance by the community, like

- [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3737139/1529630)
- [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/1529630)

More recently, I noticed there was no such list for CSS, so I created it:

[What does this symbol mean in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39710045/1529630)

I'm surprised to see that the question has received more downvotes than upvotes. There can always be some random downvotes, but even a moderator disagreed with the question arguing

> Wouldn't this be better off in the documentation section

Is it so? Now that we have Documentation, should we use it instead of this kind of dupe target lists? Is there anything bad with them? Are they discouraged?

Comment: We should still have the canonical, at least until you can close questions as duplicates of documentation. Unrelated, you should ask a moderator to turn the CSS symbol question into wiki.

Comment: @approxiblue I have flagged, for some reason the community wiki checkbox doesn't include the question.

Comment: Don't let documentation interfere with Q&A...

Comment: The very existence of the [PHP reference question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338070/792066) was challenged recently. I'm not sure why you import that same problem to other tags. In any case, such content should live on a wiki, Q&A doesn't lend itself to such things, and Documentation seems to not be able either.

Comment: I personally hate it when posts like that are used as dupe targets.

Comment: @TinyGiant In my opinion these lists should be used to find the dupe target, not as the dupe target itself.

Comment: @Braiam I didn't know about that meta question when I posted mine. And that post criticizes that the PHP reference contains not only links but answers, but I didn't import this problem to CSS. I posted the CSS reference as a community wiki.

Comment: And what relationship should such wiki questions have to the tag's info page (e.g., the [CSS info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/css/info))? If the community agrees that such wiki questions have value, one could argue for adding prominent links to them in the tag info pages.

Comment: @Oriol then why not put it in the tag wiki?

Comment: @TinyGiant I didn't think about that. But maybe because there are already various things in the tag wiki, it may be better to have a reference only for syntax.

Comment: @Oriol The python room has it's own [website dedicated for links to canonicals](http://sopython.com/canon/)

Comment: A little related: [will-there-be-a-close-reason-for-covered-in-docs](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328658/)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I support this question existing; Documentation is clearly a non-ideal candidate for the role that this question seeks to perform, since:

- given the [widespread community opposition to the entire project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339391/is-documentation-failing), it may disappear completely within a year or two
- there are too many syntactically meaningful symbols in CSS to fit each as an Example in a single Topic, and trying to fit all of this information into a single 'Example' would mean having an example containing dozens of distinct questions' worth of content
- Documentation ought to be basically self-contained, not just a collection of Stack Overflow links - but producing such self-contained documentation would mean redoing scores of man hours' of labour writing syntax explanations that *already exist* in Stack Overflow answers
- even if we did create self-contained Documentation about all syntax in CSS, it would be of zero use to people seeking duplicate targets
- heck, that Documentation probably already exists amongst the mass of [CSS Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/topics) that there is, but what use is any of it? Since Documentation is (intentionally) just an unstructured mass of random stuff, there's no way that I can look up a piece of syntax in it, which is what this reference is meant to be for. The use case for this reference (to be a structured index of, well, *documentation*) is one that it's impossible for *Documentation* to fulfil *by design*.

My only criticism is that you should have immediately flagged your question to be wiki-locked (I've now done so, and it's been locked). Failure to do this results in people coming along and adding explanations of arbitrary bits of syntax as *answers* to the reference question, which turns it into gigantic mess. (See [The "What does this symbol mean in PHP" reference is a mess](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338070/1709587).)

Comment: Should the JS question also be wiki locked, then?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I've already flagged it.

Comment: HELL YEAH, lets frame crap and put it in the middle of the dinning room, so everyone can see it.

Comment: @Braiam I do not know what your comment is meant to mean.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112910/213575

Comment: @Braiam I don't see the relevance of that post, or understand what you're trying to say. Wiki-locks aren't for 'crap', nor for 'old questions'; they're for collaborative references that don't benefit from having random extra answers added.

Answer (score 40):

1. You cannot close questions as duplicates of Docs.SO items.
2. Docs.SO is far too new and unreliable to be used as dupe-targets for such things at present.

Answer (score 2):

Currently as you know Documentation is in beta and anyone can edit as per their knowledge. if you dupe close to the documentation and if in future the example is changed and or deleted for whatever reason the future visitor will be left clueless.

Because there is no protected or locked feature in documentation to prevent other new user or less knowledgeable user on particular tag/field to contribute. This is main reason in case of wiki posts that they are protected and locked to prevent further unnecessary changes.

I think one can do is to direct the user to documentation with the help of comment.

**Edit**: As everyone know here that protected questions prevent new user, sock puppets, spammer to give answer on post which applied mainly on wiki posts and posts with high amount of upvotes but it is not in the case of documentation.

And most of the time anybody dupe close a question it happens on highly upvoted question which is protected as well.

As shown here [How to report users spamming in Documentation requests?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339215/how-to-report-users-spamming-in-documentation-requests)

> What are protected questions?
>
> A protected question prevents answers being added by anonymous and
>   very new users.
>
> Questions should be protected when they are garnering lots of views
>   and newbies are adding "me too!", "thanks!" and possibly even spam
>   non-answers.

So my point here is documentation has no safety measure right now to prevent the above mentioned and not every user know about the reviews & edits happened on documentation.

As i answered in those questions that users are unaware that where to find the edits happened on any particular example.

[Incorrect review: plagiarised material with added spam links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340501/incorrect-review-plagiarised-material-with-added-spam-links/340505#340505)

[Why has my proposal disappeared?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339671/why-has-my-proposal-disappeared/339674#339674)

Comment: Documentation links (at least those produced by the Share button), contain a timestamp, which directs users to the version that timestamp represents, so the point about the example changing is less of a problem.

Comment: Questions and answers are just as open to being changed as Documentation examples...

Comment: @TinyGiant Q&A, wiki posts which are protected and/or locked are not subject to change from new user meanwhile documentation examples are able to changed by anyone and can be reviewed by anyone regardless of their knowledge in that field because there are very less people interested in to keep track of changes in documentation.

Comment: On-topic Q&A posts are rarely if ever locked. Community wiki posts are even more open to being edited than normal Q&A. The entire system is predicated upon editing. I have seem many very misguided edits from low rep users that have been somehow approved by reviewers in the suggested edit queue and left like that for some period of time. If you want to link to something that will always be the way it is now, don't link to SO.